# Find a missing value to solve an equation

Tags: python, scipy, solver

Is there any way to solve an equation for any singular missing variable without having to rewrite the equation in different ways? I wrote this to show what I mean:

```
def solve_drag(fd = None, p = None, v = None, cd = None, a = None):
    """Takes 4 inputs out of the 5 listed and returns what the other must equal."""
    def drag(fd, p, v, cd, a):
        return (0.5 * p * v**2 * cd * a) - fd
    
    if fd == None:
        return scipy.optimize.fsolve(drag, 25, args=(p, v, cd, a))
    elif p == None:
        return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda p, v, cd, a, fd: drag(fd, p, v, cd, a),
                            1, args=(v, cd, a, fd))
    elif v == None:
        return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda v, cd, a, fd, p: drag(fd, p, v, cd, a),
                            1, args=(cd, a, fd, p))
    elif cd == None:
        return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda cd, a, fd, p, v: drag(fd, p, v, cd, a),
                            1, args=(a, fd, p, v))
    elif a == None:
        return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda a, fd, p, v, cd: drag(fd, p, v, cd, a),
                            1, args=(fd, p, v, cd))
```

It works but feels really clunky and will be long and annoying to get to work with multiple different functions. Is there a way I could make a function that takes in the function to solve and the known variables to return the variable that was missing?

Comment: Seems like SymPy would be the better choice for this: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/intro.html#introduction You could solve your equation for each variable, and get the equation for each variable. Then, when you want to calculate, you could take the solved equation and plug in values.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
def drag(fd, p, v, cd, a):
    return (0.5 * p * v**2 * cd * a) - fd
    
def solve_drag(*args):
    """Takes 4 inputs out of the 5 listed and returns what the other must equal."""
    i = args.index(None)
    return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x: drag(*args[:i], x, *args[i+1:]), 1)
```

Note that this can be extended to any function of any number arguments:

```
def solve(f, args):
    i = args.index(None)
    return scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x: f(*args[:i], x, *args[i+1:]), 1)
    
solve(drag, (1,2,None,3,4))
```

Comment: Ayyy. That's exactly what I wanted! I didn't think of using the args with the list operations like that. Thank you